# Handle friendly fire collision detection

Tags: libgdx, collision

I want to create a friendly-fire mechanism. Essentially, my cubes fire repeatedly a bullet to hit enemies. I also want to detect the hit between the bullet and another cube (friendly fire). In order to avoid that the bullet's boundaries overlap with the cube that fired it, in my "Cube" class i overrided equals. Each Cube has a unique id, initialized as soon as the Cube is created.

The issue is that i have a very bad bug. When i add the first Cube all behaves normally, but as soon as i add the second one, a collision is detected for both the cubes' bullets, instantly, even if they are not firing to each other. This happens even if i add more cubes. I checked the boundaries and they seems fine.

I put some code:

**collision detection**

```
// check collisions between bullets and cubes (friendly fire)
    for(BaseBullet bullet : bullets) {
        for(BaseSquare square : squares) {
            // exclude collision between bullet and its own Cube
            if (!bullet.getBaseSquare().equals(square)) {
                // check if bounds overlap
                if (square.getBounds().overlaps(bullet.getBounds())) {
                    System.out.println("collision between bullet and qube");
                    // propagate the event to anyone is interested in it
                    EventsManager.qubeHitByQube(bullet, square);
                    bullet.remove();
                    bulletsToDestroy.add(bullet);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**cube's equals method**

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof BaseSquare) || o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    BaseSquare baseSquare = (BaseSquare)o;
    return baseSquare.getUniqueID().equals(getUniqueID());
}
```

**NOTE**

With "friendly fire" i mean when your objects hit themselves and not the enemies.

Comment: i updated the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect the problem is more likely coming from 'if (square.getBounds().overlaps(bullet.getBounds()))' than the square's equals() method.

Are 'BaseBullet' and 'BaseSquare' extending LibGDX's Sprite class?  Should you not be calling getBoundingRectangle()?

Comment: No they are not extending Sprite class. BaseSquare extends Image and BaseBullet extends Actor. Anyway, i figure out that i initialize their bounds in a wrong way. I will try to fix it and i'll let you know if it works.